# Retrieve data from Firebase Ionic 3

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework

I have the next problem:

I want retrieve data from Firebase Database but I don't know what I have bad in my code:

This is home.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireObject, AngularFireList} 
from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  viviendas: AngularFireList<any>;

  constructor(db2: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.viviendas = db2.list('viviendas');
    console.log(this.viviendas);
  }

}
```

This is home.html

```
<ion-content padding>
<p>Prueba</p>
<li *ngFor="let vivienda of viviendas | async">
  {{ vivienda | json }}
</li>
```

My Firebase Database JSON:

[image]

I don't know how work my code, could someone explain step by step how to do it ?, I would appreciate it very much

And error:

[image]

Comment: what does the console.log give you?

Comment: I publish now my console in my question.

Comment: viviendas should be of type observable

Comment: AngularFireList is like FirebaseListObservable, if I put Observable, I can't db2.list()

Comment: I have other error, uncaught promise.... I don't know exactly what happen

Comment: Okay, maybe I can solve the error, I imported AngularFireList in app.component.ts and show JSON data

Answer (score 0):

Use the method .valueChanges()

```
this.viviendas = db2.list('viviendas').valueChanges();
```